# How to attach two (or more) networks to a container so they are available when the container starts?

Tags: docker, networking

I noticed if you try to attach a container to two networks, the following syntax does not cause an error, but effectively attach the container only on the network specified by the last `--network`:

```
sudo docker run \
        --network front-end \
        --network back-end \
        --name app1 ${IMAGE}

sudo docker network inspect front-end | jq '.[].Containers[].Name'
# <-- nothing here
sudo docker network inspect back-end | jq '.[].Containers[].Name'
"app1"
```

How to attach two (or more) networks to a container so they are available when the container starts?

Answer (score 1):

### Do that:

You cannot attach several networks using the `--network` option. You have to rely on the [`docker network connect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/) command. So if you want the multiple network interfaces to be available at container startup, you have to do it in three steps:

1. *create* the container,
2. *connect* the extra network needed,
3. and finally *run* the container.

```
# create a container, attaching it to one user-defined bridge:
docker create --name app3 \
              --network back-end \
              ${IMAGE}

# connect the other bridge networks:
docker network connect front-end app3

# start the container
docker start app3
```

```
docker exec -it app3 ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
465: eth1@if466: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:13:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.19.0.3/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
467: eth0@if468: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:14:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.20.0.3/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

### Dont' do that:

It is tempting to do that instead:

```
# You probably DON'T want this:
# create a container with the default network settings
docker create --name app3 \
              ${IMAGE}

# connect the user-defined bridge networks:
docker network connect back-end app3
docker network connect front-end app3

# start the container
docker start app3
```

However, there is a pitfall here: when creating the container without an explicit `--network` option, Docker attaches it to the default bridge. Then the two `network connect` commands will add two *more* networks. And the container end-up bein attached to the *front_end* and *back_end* networks as expected. But also to the *default bridge*, something you probably don't want when using user-defined networks.